# Working with incomplete parquet files, Parquet magic bytes not found in footer

Tags: parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I want to be able to work with parquet files which were not fully closed when written to disk.

Basically I generate some data from a C++ application using arrow RecordBatchBuilder + the parquet writer, and I create row groups whenever I have a new batch of data. When the C++ application crashes, I may not correctly clean up the parquet file handle. Also I may want to read the data while the C++ application is still running and appending more data to it.

According to https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/data-pages/errorrecovery/, it should be possible to work with data that is incomplete so long as it has some complete row groups.

When I read the data from Python with pandas+pyarrow, I get "Parquet magic bytes not found in footer". How can I make it so that it just processes the row groups that were fully written?

Alternatively, is there a way for me to write the data such that I can flush any outstanding data whenever I write a batch and generate a valid parquet file?
I could of course generate a new parquet file for each batch, which would do what I want, but that sort of breaks the point of having row groups in the first place.

import pandas as pd
pd.read_parquet('path/to/my/file.parquet')

I get
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Could not open Parquet input source '': Parquet magic bytes not found in footer. Either the file is corrupted or this is not a parquet file.

I expect to be get a dataframe with a warning that file was truncated.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided says:

```
If an error happens while writing the file metadata, all the data written will be unreadable. This can be fixed by writing the file metadata every Nth row group.
```

To my knowledge no reference implementation has implemented the second sentence (especially with sync markers), and C++/Python hasn't.

You might have better luck writing out the batches using the [Arrow IPC format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/ipc.html), with RecordBatchStreamWriter and then trying to read them one by one and catching what would hopefully be an error reading the last incomplete batch.  Once you have the record batch you can convert them to Pandas via pyarrow.